# Multicolumn and graphics

Tags: diagrams

If you try to comment what i have marked you will see the heading picture step one page back respect the title why? [Here](https://github.com/raphink/geneve_1564/blob/master/genese_heading.pdf?raw=true) is the picture. The code is from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) post.

```
\documentclass[%
              twocolumn,            %   COMMENT THIS
              a4paper,%                   % carta A4
              ]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}                      % immagini

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% Bible books (capitoli)
\newcommand{\bbook}[4][]{%
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=6in]{#4}}
  \chapter[#1]{#2,\\\large #3\\\char"2766}
}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]%
   {\centering\huge}%
   {}%
   {0pt}%
   {}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{5pt}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond 12 Regular}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[               %   COMMENT THIS

\begin{@twocolumnfalse}   %   COMMENT THIS

\bbook{Title}{title.}{genese_heading}

\end{@twocolumnfalse}     %   COMMENT THIS

]                         %   COMMENT THIS

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not related to the problem probably, but are you sure that `pagesize=pdftex` and `headinclude=on` are valid options? The first one doesn't really make sense to me (but I could be wrong) and I can't find it in the Koma-script manual. The second one should be only `headinclude` or, at least, `headinclude=true`

Comment: Also it would be a lot easier to debug if you made a _Minimal_ example not using all the fonts and and just using \vspace{3cm} in space of the image. Presumably your positioning issue does not depend on any of them but it is very hard to run your example

Comment: Sorry, i have simplified my code...

Comment: Please fix your broken links.

Answer (score 6):

Having simplified it so it runs (I see you did that later anyway, thanks) it is simply that `\chapter` does a clearpage so starts on a new page leaving the image on an earlier page, but when done inside the `\twocolumn` argument it is happening inside a minipage so page breaking is disabled. If the image is part of a fancy chapter opener it should be *part* of the definition of `\chapter` not before it.

```
\documentclass[%
              twocolumn,            %   COMMENT THIS
              twoside,%
              a4paper,%                   % carta A4
%              paper=a4,
              pagesize=pdftex,
              12pt,
              headinclude=on
              ]{scrbook}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}


\newenvironment{comment}
  {\par\itshape\scriptsize\hspace{-1em}}
  {\par}

% Bible books (capitoli)
\newcommand{\bbook}[4][]{%
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{---IMAGE---}%
  \chapter[#1]{#2,\\\large #3\\\char"2766}
}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]%
   {\centering\huge}%
   {}%
   {0pt}%
   {}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{5pt}

% Bible chapters (sezioni)
\newcommand{\bchapter}{%
   \setcounter{verse}{0}%
   \section{}{}
}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\roman{section}}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]%
   {\booktitlefont\centering}%
   {{capitolo\ \thesection}.}%
   {5pt}%
   {}
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

%*********************************************************************************
% Font
%*********************************************************************************


\begin{document}

%\twocolumn[               %   COMMENT THIS
%\begin{@twocolumnfalse}   %   COMMENT THIS
\bbook{Title}{title.}{genese_heading}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
{ argomento}.
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\parbox{4.65in}{
\begin{comment}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{comment}
}
\end{center}
%\end{@twocolumnfalse}     %   COMMENT THIS
%]                         %   COMMENT THIS

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks ! but i have not understand what i must make for make it work. I have try your code but i have the same problem.

Comment: well a cheap trick would be to use \cleardoublepage\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} instead of \twocolumn[ and \end{minipage} instead of ] in the one column case so you get the same effect of page breaking being disallowed.

Comment: i have post the final code is it correct?

Comment: well I removed a blank line so the `\noindent` applies to the minipage, but that's what I meant yes. Note thi sis easy but suboptimal as it boxes the chapter head, almost certainly the scrbook headings have stretchable glue space to help with page breaking, but putting tings in a box forces the glue to its natural width. As I mentioned in the original answer a full fix would be to modify the chapter heading code and insert the image within that at a suitable point re page and line breaking.

Answer (score 1):

**THANKS DAVID CARLISLE**

```
\cleardoublepage\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\bbook{Title}{title.}{genese_heading}

\end{minipage}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
```

Comment: Is it better regarded as an answer or a comment?